# How read data from serialport?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, embedded

I write simple program to send i read data form serial port. I was able to send the message correctly (and I correctly received it on my another device), but when I try to read a message sent form another device it get an error:

```
Error reading: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This is my code:

```
char port_name[] = "/dev/ttyACM0";

    int port = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(port < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    struct termios settings;
    memset(&settings, 0, sizeof(settings));

    tcgetattr(port, &settings);

    cfsetispeed(&settings, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&settings, B9600);
    settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    settings.c_cflag |= CS8;
    settings.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    settings.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH);
    int er = tcsetattr(port, TCSANOW, &settings);
    if(er < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error set: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    char* str = "ABCD";

    int res = write(port, str, strlen(str));
    if(res < 0){
        return;
    }

    char buffer[1000];
    memset(&buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

    int n = read(port, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if(n < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    printf("Read %i bytes. Reseived message: %s", n, buffer);

    close(port);
```

How could I fix that?

Comment: Nothing c++ relevant in this code, it's plain c. Changed the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened the device with `O_NDELAY`, which places the descriptor into non-blocking mode. If there is nothing to be read then `EWOULDBLOCK` is returned from `read`. You could for example:

- remove `O_NDELAY` from there for this simple program
- use `poll`/`select` etc to wait for the descriptor to become readable.

Comment: Your solution helped. You might know how to clear the received message from whitespace like "\ n"? The currently received message contains the phrase of the command sent + whitespace + received message. For example "Send \ n \ n \ n \ n \ Received \ n \ n"